# jQuery using variable name instead id name

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a quick question. I don't know why this is not working.
I am using a variable name instead the id.

```
var navWrapper = $('#nav');
var headParentUL = $(this).parents(navWrapper + ' > ul');
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd need to test in order to find out what results when you add a string to an object but, most likely, it isn't a CSS selector.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3e93r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `id` in variable instead of `jQuery` object

```
var navWrapper = '#nav';
var headParentUL = $(this).parents(navWrapper + ' > ul');
```

Comment: Does it work if you do not use variable? also show us the html

Answer (score 0):

Using an Object wont work.

Option 1:

```
var navWrapper = '#nav';
var headParentUL = $(this).parents(navWrapper + ' > ul');
```

Option 2:

```
var navWrapper = $('#nav');
var headParentUL = $(this).parents(navWrapper.attr('id') + ' > ul');
```

Option 3:

```
var navWrapper = $('#nav');
var headParentUL = $(this).parents(navWrapper).children('ul');
```